# Render Animation on still scene, No BVH reloading

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have a scene I would like to do a fly-through on. There are quite a few polygons. This means that blender spends quite a lot of time loading the scene before it stars to render it. It should not reload the scene because nothing has changed (except the camera). Is there a way to tell blender to only load the scene once and then just re-use what is in the RAM? I am using cycles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the performance panel of the render tab, check *Cache BVH*:

[image]

This will make Blender use the last BVH built when you press F12.

If you want faster render times for the viewport, change *Dynamic BVH* to *Static BVH*:
[image]